# Getting value of child element inside table

Tags: jquery, input, html-table, each

Why is no value returned from the "children ID"? The loop should be working, since its counting the right number of table rows ..

```
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input id="K9BEM" value"test12345" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <input id="K9BEM" value"test6789" />
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
var count = 1;
var postdata = {};
var listname = "WBEMLIST";

$('#bem_area tbody tr').each(function (index, element) {
    countName = '0000' + count;
    countName = countName.substring(countName.length - 4, countName.length);

    postdata += "test=" + $(element).children("#K9BEM").val();

    count++;
});
```

Comment: `ID`'s should be unique. Also, are you trying to make a string, an array or an object with `postdata`?

Comment: First: %s/value"/value=", Second: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, element `id`s must be unique. I've changed them to use classes.

Second, `children()` is for direct descendants. Your `input`s are two levels down from the `tr`.

Third, I don't think concatenating a string to an object is what you want to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/NcVTa/

```
var count = 1;
var postdata = '';
var listname = "WBEMLIST";

$('#bem_area tbody tr').each(function (index, element) {
    countName = '0000' + count;
    countName = countName.substring(countName.length - 4, countName.length);
    postdata += "test=" + $(element).find(".K9BEM").val();

    count++;
});
```